# How to call a async method from synchronous method?

Tags: asynchronous

I'm trying to call an asynchronous method from a synchronous method like below:

```
1.  public List<Words> Get(string code)
    {           
        Task<List<Words>> taskWords = GetWordsAsync(code);
        var result = taskWords.Result;
        return result;

    }
    private  async Task<List<Words>> GetWordsAsync(string code)
    {
        var result = await codeService.GetWordsByCodeAsync(code);
        return result;
    }
```

But this lead to a deadlock, await is not getting the results from the method - GetWordsByCodeAsync
I've done a bit of research and came to know that if we are calling an async method from synchronous method we should use Task.Run

When I changed the code like below, it worked:

```
2.  public List<Words> Get(string code)
    {           
       Task<List<Words>> taskWords = Task.Run<List<Words>>(async () => await GetWordsAsync(code);
        var result = taskWords.Result;
        return result;

    }
    private  async Task<List<Words>> GetWordsAsync(string code)
    {
        var result = await codeService.GetWordsByCodeAsync(code);
        return result;
    }
```

But I didn't get the context, why it caused a deadlock for 1st way and 2nd one worked fine.

I'd like to know: 
What's the difference between two ways?
Is second one the correct way to call async method from synchronous method? 
Will using the second method also causes a deadlock at some point of time if the result is large? or is it fail proof(safe) method to use?

Also, please suggest any best practices to better do it as I have to do 5 async calls from a synchronous method - just like taskWords, I have taskSentences etc.,

Note: I don't want to change everything to async. I want to call async method from synchronous method.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to change everything to async. I want to call async method from synchronous method.

From a technical standpoint, this doesn't make sense. Asynchronous means it doesn't block the calling thread; synchronous means it does. So you understand that if you block on asynchronous code, then it's no longer truly asynchronous? The only benefit to asynchronous code is that it *doesn't* block the calling thread, so if you block on the asynchronous code, you're removing all the benefit of asynchrony in the first place.

The only **good** answer is to go [`async` all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). There are some rare scenarios where that's not possible, though.

> What's the difference between two ways?

The first one executes the asynchronous code directly and then blocks the calling thread, waiting for it to finish. You're [running into a deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) because the asynchronous code is attempting to resume on the calling context (which `await` does by default), and presumably you're running this code on a UI thread or in an ASP.NET Classic request context, which only allow one thread in the context at a time. There's already a thread in the context (the one blocking, waiting for the task to finish), so the `async` method cannot resume and actually finish.

The second one executes the asynchronous code on a thread pool thread and then blocks the calling thread, waiting for it to finish. There is no deadlock here because the asynchronous code resumes on its calling context, which is a thread pool context, so it just continues executing on any available thread pool thread.

> Is second one the correct way to call async method from synchronous method?

There is no "correct" way to do this. There are a variety of hacks, each of which has different drawbacks, and **none** of which work in every situation.

> Will using the second method also causes a deadlock at some point of time if the result is large? or is it fail proof(safe) method to use?

It will not deadlock. What it does, though, is execute `GetWordsAsync` on a thread pool thread. As long as `GetWordsAsync` can be run on a thread pool thread, then it will work.

> Also, please suggest any best practices to better do it

I have written an [article on the subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx). In your case, if `GetWordsAsync` is safe to call on a thread pool thread, then the "blocking thread pool hack" is acceptable.

Note that this is **not** the best solution; the best solution is to go async all the way. But the blocking thread pool hack is an acceptable hack if you *must* call asynchronous code from synchronous code (again, it's "acceptable" only if `GetWordsAsync` is safe to call on a thread pool thread).

I would recommend using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` rather than `Result`, in order to avoid the `AggregateException` wrapper on error. Also, the explicit type arguments are unnecessary, and you can [elide `async`/`await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) in this case:

```
var taskWords = Task.Run(() => GetWordsAsync(code));
return taskWords.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```